# Can't set properties on a cloned dateinterval object in PHP

Tags: php, dateinterval

Why doesn't this work?

```
// works
$date = new DateInterval( 'P1Y' );
$date->y = '2';

// crashes
$date_clone = clone $date;
$date_clone->y = '2';
```

I get a "The connection was reset" in my browser when attempting to run this.

Comment: Perhaps this will help https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50559

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error with your statement.
Try updating php to the latests available version
if problem still appears (if you using linux - I don't know how debug this in windows environment) run: `gdb php -a`, and type your statement.
when php crashes, type `bt` and report bug on https://bugs.php.net/